# Is it bad practise to save an object to a database in a class constructor?

Tags: java, hibernate, constructor

I want to save a newly created object to a database using Java and Hibernate.
For a simple object, is it bad practice to store it in the database in its constructor? 
If so, why? 
And how should I do that instead?

```java
public class EnumObjType implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
  private Long CarId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  public Car() {
  }

  public Car(String name, boolean persist) {
    setName(name);
    if (persist == true) {
      setCarId(DB.saveEntity(this));
    }
  }

  // getters and setters
}
```

DB.class (excerpt):

```java
    public static <Obj> Long saveEntity(Obj obj) {
        Long id;
        try {
            DB.s.close();
            DB.openSession();
            DB.s.beginTransaction();            
            id = (Long) DB.s.save(obj);
            DB.s.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say yes, bad practice.  There might be occasions when you want to create a `Car` object that have nothing to do with adding a car into the database.

Comment: I updated the code to work around that issue.

Comment: Better, but I think you'll find it better in the long run if you completely give up any notion of the `Car` entity being responsible for persisting new instances of itself _ever_.  Just let `Car` be little more than a data holder, and let other classes deal with how the data is stored into and retrieved from whatever database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Boolean EnumObjType(EnumobjType obj) {

    boolean flag=false;
    int i  =(integer)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj).intValue();

    if (i > 0) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;


}
```

Always create Separate Doa Class to Save Object

Comment: would that be part of a service class in an API ?